# Как совместить запуск flask приложения с другим процессом?

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Имеется телеграм бот на flask, в котором есть функция автоматической отправки уведомлений реализованная через schedule и запускаемая отдельным процессом. При запуске приложения из gunicorn стартует класс flask приложения, shedule не запускается т.к вынесен за него. Подскажите как можно переписать данный код, чтобы shedule смог запуститься?

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
logger = telebot.logger
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

API_TOKEN = config.token
WEBHOOK_HOST = config.host
WEBHOOK_PORT = config.port
WEBHOOK_LISTEN = config.listen_ip
WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT = config.ssl_cert 
WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV = config.ssl_priv
WEBHOOK_URL_BASE = "https://%s:%s" % (WEBHOOK_HOST, WEBHOOK_PORT)
WEBHOOK_URL_PATH = "/%s/" % (API_TOKEN)

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

# Остальные методы бота выкладывать сюда не стал, дабы не раздувать и так немаленький код

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    chat_id = get_chat_id(message)
    logo = open(config.path_to_logo, 'rb')
    bot.send_photo(
        chat_id, logo, caption='Здравствуйте. Это - информационный бот компании BigTelecom.')
    menu(message)

@app.route(WEBHOOK_URL_PATH, methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)

def send_notification():
    # if datetime.datetime.now().day == 28: # Отправка напоминания о пополнении баланса каждое 28ое число
    user_data_query = 'SELECT tg_id, tariff_id, id FROM client WHERE tg_id != "0"'
    res_user_data_query_table = execute_select_query(
        user_data_query).split('__next_item__')
    for i in range(len(res_user_data_query_table)):
        row = res_user_data_query_table[i].split('__next_column__')
        if row[0] != '':
            row = {
                'tg_id': row[0],
                'tariff_id': row[1],
                'id': row[2]
            }
            res_user_data_query_table[i] = row
    for item in res_user_data_query_table:
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            try:
                balance = check_balance(item)
                monthly_query = 'SELECT monthly FROM ip_tariff WHERE id = ' + \
                    '"' + item.get('tariff_id') + '"'
                res_monthly_query = execute_select_query(
                    monthly_query).split('__next_item__')
                service_id_query = 'SELECT service_id FROM client_clientservice WHERE client_id = ' + \
                    '"' + item.get('id') + '"'
                res_service_id_query = execute_select_query(
                    service_id_query).split('__next_item__')
                discount_services = ['11', '12', '13', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22',
                                     '23', '24', '25', '31', '32', '33', '34', '37', '38', '39', '44', '45', '47', '48']
                if_discount_message = ''
                sum_services_price = 0.0
                for i in range(len(res_service_id_query)):
                    if res_service_id_query[i] != '':
                        service_price_query = 'SELECT price FROM clientservice WHERE id = ' + \
                            '"' + res_service_id_query[i] + '"'
                        res_service_price_query = execute_select_query(
                            service_price_query).split('__next_item__')
                        if res_service_id_query[i] in discount_services:
                            if_discount_message = 'Абонентская плата рассчитывается без учета скидки.'
                        sum_services_price += float(res_service_price_query[0])
                monthly = float(res_monthly_query[0]) + sum_services_price
                delta = monthly - balance
                note = 'Напоминаем: 1ого числа спишется абонентская плата, Вам необходимо внести на счет ' + str(delta) + \
                    ' руб. Произвести оплату можно нажав на кнопку Пополнить баланс в главном меню. ' + \
                    if_discount_message
                if delta < 0:
                    note = 'Напоминаем: 1ого числа спишется абонентская плата, на вашем счете достаточно средтв для оплаты наших услуг, спасибо!'
                bot.send_message(item.get('tg_id'), note)
            except telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException:
                print('no_chat with ', item.get('tg_id'))

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(send_notification)

class ScheduleMessage():
    def try_send_schedule():  # Бесконечный цикл для шедуллера
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)

    def start_process():  # Создание и запуск процесса шедуллера
        p1 = Process(target=ScheduleMessage.try_send_schedule, args=())
        p1.start()


bot.remove_webhook()
time.sleep(0.15)

bot.set_webhook(url=WEBHOOK_URL_BASE + WEBHOOK_URL_PATH,
                certificate=open(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, 'r'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ScheduleMessage.start_process()
    app.run(
        host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
        port=WEBHOOK_PORT,
        ssl_context=(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV),
        debug=False
    )
```

Команда запуска gunicorn:
gunicorn --bind my_ip:88 main:app --certfile=/path_to_cert/webhook_cert.pem --keyfile=/path_to_key/webhook_pkey.pem

Comment: Так как это два разных процесса, то нужно использовать средства межпроцессного взаимодействия, т.е. чтоб процесс со schedule посылал сообщение процессу с ботом, а уже тот собственно вызывал `bot.send_message`. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1305352/218971 и  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1300722/218971

Comment: Оно примерно так и происходит, используется multiprocessing Process.
Вопрос решил, просто вынес запуск процесса в тело бота из конструкции запуска.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился просто. Вынес запуск процесса schedule в тело бота из конструкции запуска.

```
ScheduleMessage.start_process()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    app.run(
        host=WEBHOOK_LISTEN,
        port=WEBHOOK_PORT,
        ssl_context=(WEBHOOK_SSL_CERT, WEBHOOK_SSL_PRIV),
        debug=False
    )
```