# посоветуйте максимально простой механизм для вызова python функции через web

Tags: python, websocket

Есть код телеграм бота, висящий на рабочей машине и  хорошо выполняющий свои функции.
Как можно заставить python принимать запрос на выполнение и отправку ответа через web интерфейс ?

Comment: Ну `flask` какой-нибудь прикрутить

Comment: Так вам надо бот запустить или функцию вызвать через web? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1300737/218971 может пригодится

Answer (score 0):

в общем спасибо за наводки

- помогли структуривать идею..
  начал копать про туннелирование - нашлась хорошая связка ngrok + flask
  у ngrok кста свои либы именно под flask есть.

это позволит дать через веб доступ к моим скриптам python, а чуть дальше прикрутить api через fastapi