# Обработка команд ботом

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, vkontakte-api, http

У меня есть бот, реализующий методы API ВКонтакте. Этот бот постоянно обрабатывает команды, которые приходят ему из обработчика сообщений. Всё это происходит внутри одной программы, внутри цикла run().

Я бы хотел сделать админ-панель, через которую мог бы также взаимодействовать с ботом. Например, локальное веб-приложение, сделанное с помощью Django.

Какие библиотеки/фреймворки мне необходимо для этого использовать? Какую логику необходимо реализовать?

Я так понимаю, что программа с ботом должна запускать http-сервер и постоянно прослушивать его, также, как это делает обработчик сообщений. А в это время Django должен отсылать запросы на http-сервер бота. Или есть более удобные пути решения этой проблемы?

Comment: Может Apachi Kafka реализует эту логику?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Управление веб страницей через телеграмм бота](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1300722/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0)