# Запуск django проекта с ТГ-ботом внутри

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot

Есть небольшая АПИ на джанго.
Запускаю стандартно через `python manage.py runserver` на локальном машине. Работает.

Захотел включить в проект ТГ-бота. Для начала самый простой функционал:

```
import telebot

API_KEY = API_KEY_BOT
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hello')

bot.remove_webhook()
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Так вот. Проект без бота запускается и работает. Бот отдельно от проекта тоже запускается и работает.
Но, когда я добавляю файл с ботом в проект, то при `python manage.py runserver` просто тормозится на

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...
```

Когда я комментирую 2 последние строки из бота - ожидаемо, сервер стартует, но без бота))
Подскажите, каким образом мне лучше поступить, чтобы в джанго проекте ещё и бот работал?

Comment: Стартовать бота в отдельном потоке. bot.polling блокирующий вызов

Comment: Тоже думал что-что-то с потоками надо делать. Я начинающий разработчик. Можете подсказать, что и где надо прописать, чтобы оно заработало?

Answer (score 0):

Запускайте бот в отдельном потоке-демоне. Вызов `bot.polling` блокирующий и потому занимает поток и не дает django выполняться (т.е. слушать порт, обрабатывать входящие запросы и т.д.):

```
from threading import Thread
 
...

def bot_thread():                
   bot.remove_webhook()
   bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
t = Thread(target=bot_thread)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

Но имейте ввиду, что лучше веб часть и бота разделить, об этом подробней [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1300722/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0/1300737#1300737).